# How to make persisted computed column in EF code first?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

How do I get this column as similar to a PERSISTED COMPUTED column in the database?

**My current attempt (it loads all CompCol rows with null in seed)  :**

```cs
    public class Call
    {
        public Call()
        {
        }
        
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public string CompCol
        {
            get
            {
                return "ABC-" + Convert.ToString(Id).PadLeft(5, '0');
            }
            protected set {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GlenLittle — Would you elaborate a bit. Your description seems to indicate that there's more to it than simply adding the keyword `PERSISTED` to the statement. (See my answer below for more info.)

Comment: @InteXX - I was remembering that in (very) old versions of SQL, some aspects of 'persisted' or 'computed' needed Enterprise edition. But, I think I am remembering wrong. I've removed my comment!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I found was to :

1. Make sure auto migrations are turned off. This is so that VS will generate a script (fluent api code) for us to further customise instead of just running it. So in the configuration class :

   ```
   public Configuration()
   {
       AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
   }
   ```
2. Add the field to the class and set it as computed like so, the setter is private because we obviously cannot write to a computed field :

   ```
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
   public string BreakdownNo { get; private set; }
   ```
3. Then do an `add-migration [xyz-name]` in the Package Manager Console to generate the migration code, which will appear under the migrations folder with the given name.
4. Inside the migration comment out the code in `Up()` and add custom SQL like so :

   ```
   public override void Up()
   {
       //AddColumn("dbo.Calls", "BreakdownNo", c => c.String());
       Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Calls ADD BreakdownNo AS ('BD'+RIGHT('00000'+ CAST(Id AS VARCHAR), 6))");
   }
   ```
5. Do an `update-database` in the PM and it should add the computed column properly.

**FURTHER NOTES** : If you get the formula wrong then you will have to revert back the migration by doing an `update-database -targetMigration: [name of migration to go back to]` then do another `add-migration name` and amend your formula there, finishing off with update-database. There may be a better way but this is what I found and used.

I did not however find a way to make the field persisted yet.

Comment: This is a good example of how difficult it is to get automatic migrations to work well.

Comment: Couldn't you set it to persisted by simply including the keyword `PERSISTED` in your `ALTER TABLE` statement? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql).

Comment: Update: yes, this works. We have a persisted computed column. Ex: `ALTER TABLE [LogEntries] ADD [ReportTime] AS (DATEADD(HOUR, -7, [LogTime])) PERSISTED`

Answer (score 1):

Why not calling sql like that:

```
public class demo
{
    void demoMethod()
    {
        Model1 model = new Model1();//Model1 : DbContext
        model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter table Results drop column Total; alter table Results add Total AS (Arabic + English + Math + Science)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some trouble using the method proposed in the accepted answer. I offer an alternative solution that worked for me.

I encountered a failure when running this query:

```
oDb.LogEntries.SingleOrDefault(Function(LogEntry) LogEntry.LogTime = dDate)
```

The error message:

> The 'MinutesOffline' property on 'LogEntry' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Single'.

As we can see, EF 6.2 is trying to write a value to the property. Whether this is due to EF internally attempting to write to the `Private Set`, I don't know. It almost seems like it. But the end result is what matters: the statement fails.

Instead of setting the column to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`, I ended up ignoring it altogether: `Builder.Entity(Of LogEntry).Ignore(Function(LogEntry) LogEntry.MinutesOffline)`.

This enabled me to create a read-only property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property MinutesOffline As Single
  Get
    Return IIf(Me.Scale < 1, 5, 0)
  End Get
End Property
```

It also has the added benefit that we don't have to comment out any lines in the generated migration.

We still have to make the custom `Sql()` call in `Up()`:

```
ALTER TABLE [LogEntries] ADD [MinutesOffline] AS (IIF([Scale] < 1, 5, 0)) PERSISTED
```

...and the `PERSISTED` keyword does work here. This becomes a persisted computed column.

YMMV

**--EDIT--**

I found out why I was getting the casting error; it had nothing to do with migrations and everything to do with my code. I wasn't properly casting the computed column at creation time:

```
ALTER TABLE [LogEntries] ADD [MinutesOffline] AS (IIF([Scale] < 1, 5, 0)) PERSISTED
```

The proper syntax for doing so is this:

```
ALTER TABLE [LogEntries] ADD [MinutesOffline] AS (CAST((IIF([Scale] < 1, 5, 0)) AS REAL)) PERSISTED
```

Accordingly, I've reverted the `Ignore()` calls and switched everything back over to the method proposed in the accepted answer.

Hat tip to [JotaBe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551534/722393) for the assistance.