# Define Data Type of Computed Column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a computed column specified as follows:

```
(case when [StartDate]<=getdate() AND [EndDate] IS NULL then (1) else (0) end)
```

I'm trying to use the value of this column in Entity Framework. Is there any possible way to have this recognized as a `boolean`? That, or can I have it defined as a bit in my database, based on its return values? As it is, Entity Framework considers it an `int` (as it seems to do whenever it's not clear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply cast the value to `bit`, like this:

```
CAST ((case when [StartDate]<=getdate() AND [EndDate] IS NULL 
       then (1) else (0) end) AS BIT)
```

EF will automatically recognize this column as boolean.

In fact the original query returns an integer, and that's why EF recognizes it as integer. In SQL Server, unless you say the contrary, 1 and 0 are integer values. You must use `CAST (0 as BIT)` or `CAST (1 as BIT)` if you want SQL Server to recognize them as boolean (bit) type.

Comment: Very good, thank you. I was getting an [obscure error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152464/722393) and this turned out to be the fix.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

drop table ##test;

create table ##test (

  [id] [bigint]

  , [computed] as cast([id] as [float]) * .99

  );

insert into ##test

            ([id])

values     (9999999999);

select *

from   ##test;